# NHibernate Configuration reference at runtime

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way to get a reference to NHibernate Configuration at the runtime? I need it for SchemaExport().

Update: I am using StructureMap with FluentNHibernate to set it up, but I just want to know if I can get it from SessionFactory or some other object, after SessionFactory has been initialized, without having to rewrite setup in ioc to hold on to reference to Configuration.

Comment: Sure. How are you creating your initial Configuration? fluent-nhibernate? ActiveRecord? manually?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little please?  I think I've dealt with a similar problem, but don't want to point you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how I did it.

```
  ForRequestedType<FluentConfiguration>()
            .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton)
            .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(
            ()=>Fluently.Configure()
                                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                                    .AdoNetBatchSize(10)
                                    .Driver("NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver")
                                    .ProxyFactoryFactory("NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle")
                                    .UseOuterJoin()
                                    .ConnectionString(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;User Id=epitka;Password=password;Database=dnn49;")
                                    .ShowSql()
                                    .CurrentSessionContext("thread_static")) // CHANGE THIS FOR WEB
                                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MetaProject>())
                                .ExposeConfiguration(
                                                   cfg =>{  
                                                             cfg.SetProperty(
                                                                 Environment.TransactionStrategy,
                                                                 typeof (AdoNetTransactionFactory).FullName);
                                                             cfg.SetProperty(Environment.GenerateStatistics, "true");  //REMOVE FOR LIVE
                                                   })
            )
            .WithName("SharMod_FluentConfiguration");

        ForRequestedType<Configuration>()
            .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(
            () =>
                {
                    var fc =ObjectFactory.GetInstance<FluentConfiguration>();
                    return fc.BuildConfiguration();
                })
            .WithName("SharpMod_Configuration");

        //SharpMod_SessionFactory
        ForRequestedType<ISessionFactory>()
            .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Singleton)
            .AddInstances(x => x.ConstructedBy(() =>
                                 ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<FluentConfiguration>("SharMod_FluentConfiguration")
                                .BuildSessionFactory())
                                .WithName("SharpMod_SessionFactory"));
```

Now to get it I just do:

```
var cfg = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<Configuration>("SharpMod_Configuration");
```